# Web BLE Characteristic startNotifications sometimes doesn't bind

Tags: javascript, promise, web-bluetooth

I'm using web BLE. I have based my code according to the example of the heart rate measurement.

Everything is working fine most of the time. But sometimes, **even if the connection is successfully made**, when I try to bind to the notification, it doesn't work.

The link is made in this function :

```
    _startNotifications(characteristicUuid) {
      let characteristic = this._characteristics.get(characteristicUuid);
      console.log(characteristic);
      return characteristic.startNotifications().then(() => characteristic);
    }
```

When everything is OK, I can see in the console that `BluetoothRemoteGATTCharacteristic` has a `value : DataView(2) {}`
Otherwise, when it's not working it has a `value : null`

[image]

I would like to be able to retry automatically, if I detect that the value is null. But I'm not familiar with Promise (I think this is it) and `console.log(characteristic.value)` doesn't work here.

How would you approach this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is "bypass" the issue. So it's a more algorithmic resolution than a pure Javascript one.

I didn't change the connection function, so it is still called like this :

```
device._startNotifications(some_uuid).then(handleHeartRateMeasurement)
```

I check everything in the `handleHeartRateMeasurement` function :

```
var ready = false;

function handleHeartRateMeasurement(heartRateMeasurement) {
  console.log("Hold on...");
  heartRateMeasurement.addEventListener("characteristicvaluechanged", event => {
    // Everytime the value change, this should be triggered
    // If it did not, variable "ready" will stay false
    ready = true;
    var value = device.parseValue(event.target.value);
    // Do something with value here
  });

  var check = function(){
    // If we have received data from characteristic, we are ready to go !
    if(ready === false){
      console.log("Device connected but not receiving data");

      // Stop the current notification subscription
      device.stopNotificationsHeartRateMeasurement();

      // Start a new one
      device._startNotifications(some_uuid).then(handleHeartRateMeasurement);

      setTimeout(check, 1000); // check again in a 1s
    }
    else{
      console.log("Device connected and receiving data");
    }
  }

  setTimeout(() => {
    check();
  }, 500);
}
```